# What's the Variable for Domain Root? Or a Way to go up a Directory?

Tags: php

So first check out my line of code below:

```
$env_config['tmpl_file_basepath'] = DOC_ROOT . '/tpl/';
```

DOC_ROOT is equal to $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] which is equal to /var/www/example.com/html/

So my code above would set that path to: /var/www/example.com/html/tpl/

However the tpl folder should actually be in /var/www/example.com/

So first is there any server variable that is equal to the domain root, rather than the public directory root? And if not, is there a way to go up a diretory such as:

```
$env_config['tmpl_file_basepath'] = DOC_ROOT . '../tpl/';
```

I tried that but instead it just did /var/www/example.com/html/../tpl/

If this site was just in one location, I could simply manually type in the server path, but this is a config file that is used on local, dev, and live so I can't have it hardcoded. I've gotten everything else working. Thank you!

Comment: just `dirname(DOC_ROOT)` is your variable. `/var/www/example.com/html/../tpl/` is okay too, it would work. no reason to ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To go up one directory, you can use [dirname](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php):

```
$env_config['tmpl_file_basepath'] = dirname(DOC_ROOT) . '/tpl/';
```

Comment: Damn you the man! I'm new to the site so I can't raise your Answer, but works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`/path/to/some/../location` is equal to `/path/to/location`, because `..` references the parent directory. You can use `realpath()` to resolve the path to its canonical form, but usually this is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [realpath](http://nl.php.net/realpath) to get the absolute path to the tpl dir.

```
$env_config['tmpl_file_basepath'] = realpath(DOC_ROOT . '../tpl/');
```

Did you try ussing /tpl because / would make you end up in your webdir if i'm not mistaking. Or do you want the tpl dir outside of the webroot?